# Rails Forms: How to add field beside checkboxes on Many-to-Many Relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, many-to-many, associations

So I need advice on how to set up a rails form in a many-to-many relationship where I save extra information in the join model.

Background: I have two models, User and Skill. A user can have many skills; skills can be mapped to many users. I have a join model SkillAssessment to save this, which saves a user_id, skill_id. I want to be able to save in the join model how good a user is at a skill, or skill_level. This can take integer values from 0-5.

The Skills table is prepopulated with entries, so when creating a new user I would like for the "Skills" input to be a bunch of checkboxes. I don't know how to add a field beside the checkboxes where a user can input how good he/she is at a skill. This ideally would be a drop-down, but that isn't super important.

Here is a picture of how it might look: the checkbox is on the left, followed by a label, followed by an extra field (text input, drop down.. anything) to rate the skill level.

[image: demonstration of what to do]

I have these models working great once the data is saved, but I don't know how to alter the form. If it were just saving skills, I would put:

```
 = f.input :skills, :label => _("Skills"), :as => :check_boxes, :collection => Skill.all
```

How can I achieve what I'm going for here? I thought maybe semantic_fields_for or something?

FYI I use slim and formtastic, but know haml and plain rails so advice in any format is much appreciated! Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've said everything works great once its in the database, so I'm assuming that you've set up your model as a `:has_many, :through` rather than a `has_and_belongs_to_many`.  If not, you'll need to do that to save extra attributes to your join model.

If you haven't already done so, you're going to need to turn on accepts_nested_attributes_for SkillsAssessments in your User model.

If you're using `attr_accessible` you'll also need to add `skill_assessments_attributes` to your user list of accessible attributes.

End result is that your user model would look like so:

```
models/user.rb
===============
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :skill_assessments
has_many :skills, :through => :skill_assessments

accepts_nested_attributes_for :skill_assessments

attr_accessible :user_field, ..., :skill_assessments_attributes
```

Again, if your using attr_accessible, you'll need to ensure that all three fields on your skill_assessment model are accessible.

```
models/skill_assessment.rb
===========================
class SkillAssessment < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :user
belongs_to :skill

attr_accessible :user_id, :skill_id, :skill_level
```

Then in your view, you're going to have something like this (haml):

```
views/users/_form.html.haml
============================
= semantic_form_for @user do |f| 
  = f.input :user_field_1
  ...
  = f.input :user_field_n
  = f.semantic_fields_for :skill_assessments do |sa|
    = sa.input :skill_id, :label => "Skill", :collection => Skill.all
    = sa.input :skill_level, :label => "Proficiency", :collection => [1,2,3,4,5]
  = f.submit
```

Comment: Hi Paul. Thanks for the suggestion - I was worried that I wouldn't get any responses to this question. I will try this out, and let you know if this works. Thanks again